# Why do logs inside an eval() appear later in the console than the logs after the eval()?

Tags: javascript, logging, eval, devextreme

As I am trying to figure out why the loading process of my webpage (dxview) takes so long, I decided to put some `console.log()` statements in both the code before and after an `eval()` (part of that process) and the string inside that very `eval()`. It looks somewhat like this:

```
console.log("Timestamp before eval: " + (new Date().getTime()));
eval("... console.log('Some log in here'); ...");
console.log("Timestamp after eval: " + (new Date().getTime()));
```

Interestingly, the result was in another order than I expected:

```
"Timestamp before eval: 1423852110738"
"Timestamp after eval: 1423852110787"
"Some log in here"
```

This makes it very hard to detect the actual time consuming part as using timestamps this way does not even indicate whether the `eval` is the problem.

Putting logs at the beginning and end of the eval'ed string indicate that the `eval` actually takes **250 to 350 ms** to process while the difference between the two timestamps is just **49 ms**. But until the `viewShown` method is invoked, it takes another **23,000+ ms**.

AFAIK, if you don't use web workers or timeouts/intervals, JS should continue with the code just after (and not before) a statement is done. I might be confusing something here, but how could this work then?

Kind regards,
jaySon

Comment: ps, for quick and dirty timestamps in the console, you can be lazier: `console.log("Timestamp before eval: ", +new Date );`

Comment: Or on any modern browser: `console.log(Date.now() + " ... ");`

Comment: @dandavis: `console.log` is **not** async. But if you log objects, with the console open, in some versions of the console, display of their *content* may be done later when you expand them. But logging simple strings doesn't exhibit that behavior.

Comment: **It doesn't.** jaySon, the code you've shown does not produce the output you describe: http://jsbin.com/bamupucaci/1  My guess is that the content of the `...` matters.

Comment: What is the magical code in the eval. My guess is you are doing something asynchronous.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: i misread the question and thought it took 23 seconds for the log to show up. the console rendering is async, or at least buffered internally, the actual log() call (like all js function calls) is sync.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can think of is that, in eval(), did you put the console.log() inside of an async callback, which would explain the order of the console.log messages.

If everything is sync, the order of the messages should be :

```
"Timestamp before eval: 1423852110738"
"Some log in here"
"Timestamp after eval: 1423852110787"
```

My suggestion is, instead of logging end time after eval(), figure out when the eval() part actually ends (**meaning that all the async methods finished**), and log the end time **right there**.

for example, if you have an async function inside of the eval():

```
console.log("Timestamp before eval: " + (new Date().getTime()));
eval("setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('Timestamp after eval: ' + (new Date().getTime()));
}, 1000);");
```

In this fashion, you should be able to figure out exactly how long does it take for all the functions to complete.

Thanks.